# Moving a div inside a div?

Tags: css

Hi well I basically want to move down my logo div which is inside my topBar div however when ever I use padding or margin it moves the whole top bar down or the logo just repeats its self (and yes I have tried background-repeat: no-repeat)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body lang="en">
<div class="alert">Do you want advertsing space? Contact us: <b>advertising@chattrd.com</b></div>
<div class="topBar">
<div id="logo">
<p>chattrd</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

body {
    background: #F7F7F7;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.alert {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #1f1f1f;
    height: 14px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.topBar {
    background: #0C3;
    height: 40px;
}
#logo {
    background-image:url(../images/logo.png);
    height: 26px;
    width: 121px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    text-indent:-999px;
}
```

Comment: Show the markup and CSS you have.

Comment: post your code and markup. This is a QA site, not a guessing site.

Comment: There ya go, and Ejay I just thought you may of had this kind of issue before.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is behaving this way is that you are using the image as a background. If you want to carry on with this approach, the easiest way to be able to move it vertically is to place another div before the #logo-div like so:

```
<body lang="en">
<div class="alert">Do you want advertsing space? Contact us: <b>advertising@chattrd.com</b></div>
<div class="topBar">
<div id="spaceDiv"></div>
<div id="logo"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

The height of the spaceDiv can be used to move the #logo-div using the following CSS:

```
#spaceDiv{
    height:6px;
}
```